# WooCommerce Categories / Tags Archive - 'No Products Found'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, archive

I wonder what could have caused this problem? The ‘Shop’ page is showing the products / categories (i.e. works normally) and the permalink is set to default, every page works except the Categories / Tags archive pages for WooCommerce products which will only show “No products found which match your selection.”

The products are set to be visible in both ‘Catalog and Search’ but it only appears on search results and ‘Shop’, but not the catalog (in either categories or tags).

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the culprit. It is a silly mistake which I overlooked. I added a custom post type and modified the query in functions.php to include the new custom post type in archives, but I hard-coded the post types rather than using get_post_types() to include all post types available (including those added by plugins).

The problem is already solved now. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your products are categorized or tagged? If yes, do you use defaults woocommerce templates or using custom ones in theme?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yes, they are categorized / tagged (both are listed in the individual product page). I am trying to develop a WooCommerce theme but I'm not sure which files are possibly causing the problem (as in, whether WooCommerce uses files like archive.php for its category listing). Any ideas? Thanks!